# SwiftUI: Implement consecutive long press gestures on different views while keeping the finger on the screen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a gesture interaction in SwiftUI where I have two views, View A and View B. Here is the expected interaction:

The user starts a long press on View A.
Once the long press is recognized (after a certain duration), View A is hidden, and View B is displayed.
The tricky part is that the user's finger remains on the screen throughout this transition. I want a second long press gesture to be recognized on View B while the finger is still on the screen.
When the user finally lifts their finger from View B, I want to trigger some actions.
I am struggling to implement this because when the long press gesture on View A is recognized, SwiftUI seems to end the gesture recognition, making it impossible to recognize a second long press on View B while the finger is still on the screen.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this behavior in SwiftUI? Thanks for your help!"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.